# HTML: How to get value from dropbox

Tags: html, tapestry

I have a dropbox on my application that has three options (blank space, Yes, No), populated using tapestry

This has a child dropbox which is being populated depending on what is selected from the dropbox below

I have it working so that if 'yes' or 'no' is selected the below dropbox is populated correctly. What i want do is if 'blank space' is chosen i want the below dropbox to be empty. Is there a way of doing this without using Javascript, or do you have to use Javascript?

Something like

```
<span jwcid="@If" condition="topDropBox.getSelectedValue != null" renderTag="literal:false">
```

EDIT: Javascript that i have tried

```
function getValueFromDropBox() {
              document.getElementById('topDropBox').options[document.getElementById('topDropBox').selectedIndex].value
            }
```

calling it from HTML

```
<span jwcid="@If" condition="javascript: getValueFromDropBox() != null" renderTag="literal:false">
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my thought yes you have to use javascript based on that only 
you can give this options

```
<select onclick="showdrop()">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1">YES</option>
<option value="2">NO</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have tried the above Javascript (in edit section) but that did not work either

Comment: please give the code you tried it will be helpful to continue